# Error while importing osm.bz2 to existing openstreetmap db

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

When I installed Overpass API 2 years ago (http://overpass-api.de/full_installation.html), I used the following commands to import it:

```sh
wget -O france-latest.osm.bz2 "http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/france-latest.osm.bz2"
bin/init_osm3s.sh france-latest.osm.bz2 "db/" "./" --meta
```

Now I need to add the OSM file of Netherlands as well.

When I use the same command, I am getting the following error:

```
**Context error: File db///osm3s_v0.7.53_osm_base present, which indicates a running dispatcher. Delete file if no dispatcher is running**
```

Can someone help me to solve this please ?

Comment: Is a dispatcher running? Did you try deleting this file?

Comment: The Geofabrik extract you're using only includes fake meta data. Don't use it along with `--meta`. Instead, get the full meta data files from Geofabrik instead.